# How to create an instance of a Swagger 1.2 Model in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, rest, express, swagger

I'm using **swagger-node-express** with **swagger 1.2** to define my REST api in a nodejs server.

Here is my first model:

```
exports.models = {
    "User":{
      "id":"User",
      "properties":{
        "username":{
          "type":"string",
          "description": "Username"
        },
        "firstname":{
          "type":"string",
          "description": "Firstname"
        },
        "lastname":{
          "type":"string",
          "description": "Lastname"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

I have an API endpoint /user/signup which is supposed to return a JSON representation of the signed up user.

*I would like to return a JSON object compliant with the previous model.*

Is there a way to "instanciate" a model ?

Something like:

```
var userInstance = swagger.instanciateModel( 'User' );
```

I found the **swagger-model** npm package that have a *model2Json(object)* method, but is there any other one ?

Thanks !

Comment: Do you mean you want to infer JSON based on your javascript object?  That's doable but highly unreliable, since javascript is not typed.

Comment: For example, when a new user successfully register,  i want to return a User as a JSON object matching the spec defined in it's model definition.